# Applying spring security - is this usage correct?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am applying spring security to a web application where i need to do the following:

- Limit access to certain pages for certain roles/authorities
- Limit access to certain data based on user access and user role (for
  example admin can see all data, a user can see only data on which the admin granted access for the user)
- Allow actions on data based on the access right the user has (read,
  manage, etc)

So, i was thinking:

- Limit access to certain pages for certain roles/authorities -> use
  hasRole
- Limit access to certain data -> filter directly in the queries
  getting the principal from the security context
- Allow actions on data based on the access right the user has -> use
  my custom PermissionEvluator's hasPermission method

Now this is a setup i came up with, but would like to know if this makes sens and if it is according to a good use of the spring security framework or am i simply twisting it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security provides all these features and makes implementing these features simple. Yes your approach is right. you can add below cases.

- security none: allow unauthenticated users access to certain
  pages.(login, public pages) authenticated: allow access to
- authenticated users.. (general access to all registered users)
- restrict based on role: readonly, editor/manager,  based on
- permissionEvaluator on the data user has access to

You can also use spring security to protect your web application against malicious users with features like
- CSRF protection (enabled by default)
- XSS protection 
for further detail read: spring security [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html)